# Is it possible to make a zip from one google storage bucket to another with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

recently i got a requirement to select set of files from one gcp bucket, make a zip of it and put it to another bucket. this is to make the zip file available for the user's of my system. I know that we could do like download the necessary files from the bucket make a zip and re-upload to the next bucket. But that would overwhelm my server if the number of requests increased overtime. So is there a way to do this on the bucket itself and move it to the next bucket..? im using Node.js.

Comment: You need to change the projectId and bucketName depending on case where you want the uploading to be done. More Detail on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs

Comment: @RohitDalal Sorry, but i don't think you understand my question.

Comment: My Bad, but as pointed out in below answer, its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**, there's  no way to zip up objects from a bucket into a target bucket

There is however an elegant way to do this on your own that would require three components : (1) a GCP pub/sub topic, (2) a node `/request-zip` service and (3) a cloud-compute instance-group to process the zips

#### (1) Create a pub-sub topic

```
gcloud pubsub topics create request-zip
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create --topic request-zip work-zip
```

#### (2) Create a `/request-zip` service to publish to the `request-zip` topic

The quick recipe below is pseudo-code showing how to receive the files list and enqueue it onto the `request-zip` topic. This call is fast.  You may want to add an email address or create another "done" queue to notify the caller when the work is complete.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/request-zip', (req, res) => {


  const pubsub = new PubSub({projectId});

  // send the file list to the queue
  sendMessageResponse = await pubsub.sendMessage("request-zip", req.body.files.join(','));
  console.info(sendMessageResponse)

}
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

example publish to topic on cli for testing

```
    gcloud pubsub topics publish request-zip --message "file1.txt,file2.png"
```

#### (3) Run an instance group to work the queue

Write a short shell script like the following and spin up a few instances to do the zips

#### example receive message

```
while true; do
   # i suggest testing success on all routines and then --ack at the end.
   files=$(gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull work-zip --auto-ack --format json|jq -r '. 
   [].message.data'|base64 -d)
   gsutil sync gs://my-bucket/{$files} .
   zip -r archive.zip .
   gsutil sync archive.zip gs://target-bucket/
   rm -rf *
done
```

Comment: What is `ghutil`? Did you mean `gsutil`? Does your while loop remove the files after zip and then remove the zip file?

Comment: This is an interesting answer. The code will not work as is, but can provide the basis and ideas for a real implementation.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley .  With some additional error checking and cleanup the solution should be viable.  the notification needs acked, the message should probably be json, and better error checking in both routines.  Brevity here would be more illustrative.  Glad you like the approach

Comment: Very cool idea for handling asynchronous zipping of files. I can see a couple of applications for this. Put this on App Engine and you don't even need a compute instance. App Engine will require porting this into Python or another language, but the concept is the same.

Comment: thanks a lot !  one other thought would be to run a lambda every 30s to kill or spawn instances depending on the size of the queue.  That way in cases where there is no work to be done, you don't pay any money. 

The upside of using the instances is how simple the zip routine is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189285/discussion-between-anthony-metzidis-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Hi, @AnthonyMetzidis, Sorry for the late response and thank you for responding. Im new to all of these google cloud platform technologies. could you explain this instance group and shell script usage please ?

Comment: Simple way to start would be to launch a single instance and run the script via SSH. once it's working and tested, you can create an instance-template from the working instance, and then create an instance group from that template.  instance-groups let you launch multiple instances from a template, and autoscale them.  The startup-script is metadata containing the script above that gets triggered when the instance starts.  It's a quick-and-dirty way to run code on a server.